# Efficiently comparing hashes in a MySQL data set

Tags: php, mysql, security, hash

I have an encrypted database (MySQL) which has certain columns that need to be searched by a (non-public, authorised) user.

I have been reading [this article on Database SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23908/how-to-search-a-mysql-database-with-encrypted-fields) about searching encrypted fields in a database.

I have come to a conclusion from reading this, that the best way to do this would be with a hash of the column values to compare with the given data, so:

**Example:**
Searching for a phone number.

> HTML: User enters phone number to search for
>   PHP: phone number is hashed
>  
>   MySQL: searches `hashed_phone` column(s) to compare (`=`) and returns
>   matching results.
>   PHP: matching result rows are decrypted and then output to user.

Given the small caveat that I can't search *part of* a phone number (which would be ideal in concept but well outside the scope of this specific question), I find an issue that:

Using secured hashing algorithms (`password_hash`, etc) all use a salt as a best practise, and this **entirely makes sense** *BUT* gives me an issue in that if I create the hash of the search term plus the salt, this makes the hash ***different*** from the stored database value, I can't then use a comparison operator to find the correct row(s) from the Dataset.

In Summary:

- How can I solve this issue and have encrypted data that can be subject to some degree of searching without needing to decrypt each row of the dataset individually?
- Can I use a *secure* hashing algorithm that does not use a salt (as opposite as that sounds), without leaving a [potential] gaping hole in the security risk of the data at rest (at least, for those columns)?

  - Is there an alternative methodology I've not thought of?
- I would like the MySQL side of things to be as efficient as possible, there are thousands of rows in the dataset so going through each one to then decrpyt and check is deeply inefficient.

## How can I do this?

Comment: sounds like XY problem, why do you store encrypted data if you can't decrypt it? do you just need extra security in case database is leaked?

Comment: Have you considered encrypting the whole table(s) and letting MYSQL do all the heavy lifting?

Comment: @Peter Actually hashing is not encryption!

Comment: @Peter It can be decrypted, but it's hugely inefficient to decrypt all rows of a dataset simply to return 2 rows (for example) to the browser.

Comment: @RiggsFolly i am asking about encrypted data.

Comment: @Martin so if it can be decrypted *why* do you need to store it encrypted?

Comment: @RiggsFolly having MySQL internally encrypt the data is not an option. MySQL encyption practises are insecure and leave plaintext footprints all over the DB server (such as in query logs, etc.).

Comment: @Peter it is data at rest, so that if the DB admin or if the SQL gets exported, or the SQL server is compromised then the data within the server is not at risk. Security 101.

Comment: keep things simple, use `password_hash` on one side with bcrypt, and store it on db.  `password_verify ` on another side to verify the input string matches the hash. albeit it is in ruby, but you can grasp the logic -https://www.blackbytes.info/2017/06/there-is-no-magic-in-ruby/

Comment: @marmeladze the problem is that hashing with `password_hash` uses a salt and so different instances of `password_hash` on the same plaintext will produce non-identical strings. ***that*** is my issue.

Comment: If I understood your problem correctly, you could simply use a fixed salt for [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) (by setting `'salt'` in the `options`-array). Or, since the `'salt'` option will be removed in a later version of php, you can use [`crypt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) directly (with fixed algorithm and salt). The same phone number (especially "empty") will now have the same hash value (in contrast to a password list where same passwords/different salts have different hashes), but you actually WANT same hash for same number.

Comment: @Solarflare yes I think I need something like that, but this comment is just to clarify that empty values will be `NULL` so won't need to be hashed at all.